# update NamespaceURI of node in XML Document

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I have the following piece of code:

```
root = parser.parse(xmldoc)
Node item = root.children().find { it.name().getLocalPart() == element }
if (item) {
    // update namespace uri
}
```

Below is an example:

```
<ct:Description xmlns:ct="http://somewhere.com">Semi-mechanistic modelling of the tumour growth inhibitory effects of LY2157299</ct:Description>
```

I get the namespace URI using the method `getNamespaceURI()` on the object `item.name()`. For the time being, how can I update that property.

If I print out `item.name()`'s properties, they include:

```
[localPart:Description, class:class groovy.xml.QName, qualifiedName:ct:Description, prefix:ct, namespaceURI:http://somewhere.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

Discussing on this with my team mate in this earlier morning, we have found a solution. To update namespace, you can use the `replaceNode` method. Details of the solution is presented as below:

```
import groovy.xml.QName
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
import org.xml.sax.SAXException
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom as R

File f = new File("/tmp/test.xml")
f.exists()

String elem = "Description"
int count = R.current().nextInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
String value = "my example value ${count}"
String elemNs = "http://www.somewhere.else/oldns"
String newElemNs = "http://www.somewhere.else/newns"

XmlParser parser = new XmlParser(false, true)
def root = parser.parse(f)
Node item = root.children().find { it.name().getLocalPart() == elem }
item.name = new QName(newElemNs, item.name().getLocalPart(),item.name().getPrefix())
XmlUtil.serialize(root, new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f)))
```

The snapshot above aims to update the namespace of the node found in the xml document. Then, save the change back to the file.